# Getting Byte Array with all values zero

Tags: arrays, groovy

I have printed the byte array of image

```
def files = request.getParts()

for(Part file in files) {
    println file.getSubmittedFileName() + " " + file.getSize()
    InputStream initialStream = file.getInputStream()
    byte[] buffer = new byte[initialStream.available()]

    println buffer
    println "--------"
}
```

This is output generated:

```
null 18
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
--------
null 2
[0, 0]
--------
Signature.pdf 13722
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ]
--------
```

The last array is not the complete one. I have shortened the output. But all the values are zero.
I could not figure it out why I am getting zeros in byte array.

Comment: An `array` in Java defaults to having all `0`s. Did you assign any values to it?

Comment: @luk2302 this is groovy

Comment: @notyou I did not. How Can I get Image in byte array from above code.

Answer (score 0):

That's correct, default value of `byte` after allocation is `0`. As per [Primitive Data Types docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html):

> Data Type | Default Value (for fields)
>
> byte | 0

You only allocated the `buffer` array in your code, you haven't written any values.

Comment: how can I convert file into BufferedImage in groovy.

Comment: @SanjeevBudha Use `ImageIO.read()` metods e.g. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read(java.io.InputStream